# YOCTO QA Issue: xxx contained in package my-package requires libzlog.so.1.2()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS

Tags: dependencies, yocto, recipe

Got an error while bitbake my package:
ERROR: my-opt-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /opt/bin/sps contained in package my-opt requires libzlog.so.1.2()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_my-opt? [file-rdeps]

It should simple copy some files to my image.

The recipe looks like:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Copy some files to rootfs"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"

RDEPENDS_{PN} = "zlog"

SRC_URI += " \
  file:///home/user/ws/libvision-device/libvision-device.h \
  file:///home/user/ws/libvision-device/libvision-device_em5m.so \
  file:///home/user/ws/sps/sps \
"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}/opt/lib
    install -m 644  /home/user/ws/libvision-device/libvision-device.h  ${D}/opt/lib
    install -m 644  /home/user/ws/libvision-device/libvision-device_em5m.so  ${D}/opt/lib/libvision-device.so
    install -d ${D}/opt/bin
    install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/home/user/ws/sps/sps ${D}/opt/bin
}

#PACKAGES = "${PN}"

FILES_${PN} += " \
    /opt/lib \
    /opt/bin \
"
```

The strange is: I give the dependency via RDPENDS. Look:

```
oe-pkgdata-util find-path '*libzlog.so.1.2'
zlog-dbg: /usr/lib/.debug/libzlog.so.1.2
zlog: /usr/lib/libzlog.so.1.2
```

So what is my mistake? Who and how checks magically what "sps" depends on?
If I have that under control in my image, any chance to disable that checks (ok, that's dirty, but I am clueless).